# ASP.NET Core Kestrel throughput

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I create an empty asp.net core project base on .net6 and do load testing using python locust. The average response time is about 900ms, but using MiniProfile monitors the API executed time, almost zero. That's why? How to optimize it?

Load test result:
[image]

Use MiniProfile to monitor the APIs execution time:
[image]

Resource usage:
[image]

Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddMiniProfiler(opt =>
{
    opt.RouteBasePath = "/profiler";

});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiniProfiler();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

HomeController.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace del.Controllers;

[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() => Ok();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post() => Ok();
}
```

Python script:

```py
from locust import HttpUser, task


class Date(HttpUser):
    @task
    def get_date(self):
        self.client.get('/home')
```

Comment: Are you running everything on the same machine? You can try installing fiddler or wireshark to see that actual request-response take that much time. Or do several request with postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

locust has some performance problems